# TransformControl behind SpriteControl

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality, perspectivecamera

I am having a issue with using TransformControl with Sprite materials. Transform control works good with Geometry materials. But when I attach a Sprite material, TransformControl's axis are always behind the Sprite material. Is this such a issue do you thing or what? `[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccaymaz/u279drpm/)`

Thank you

Comment: can we see a example?

Comment: There is an ugly sample but still same. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccaymaz/u279drpm/)

Comment: `TransformControl` was not designed to work with `Sprite`s.

Comment: thank you for your answer. If it is not fit sprites, what is the best object? I want all meshes to point to the screen.